# Настройка автоматической синхронизации USB флешки с папкой на локальной машине

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, kali-linux

Мне нужно, чтобы определённая папка на флешке и определённая папка на машине синхронизировались, и желательно не тупо перезаписывались, а на обоих копиях сохранялась последняя версия содержимого.

Comment: Попробуй rsync.

Comment: Если бы вы были конкретней, было бы полезней

Comment: Я тебе дал концепцию, как ты и просил ранее. Дальше - сам, там ничего сложного, честное слово.

Comment: @donRumata *на обоих копиях сохранялась последняя версия содержимого.*  Лет 10 назад я занимался этой проблемой (синхронизацией нескольких распределённых систем) довольно подробно. И пришёл к однозначному выводу - это невозможно. Обязательно должен быть **эталон**, по которому синхронизируются все остальные.  Иначе получается полный бред.  Простейший случай: на флэшку записали файл А, а в каталог на компе - файл Б.  Какая из этих двух версий **более** последняя? :-) Сравнивать по датам модификации? А вы готовы снести файл пользователя на флэшке, который он туда записал на 1 минуту ранее?

Comment: @donRumata А если несколько флэшек носят между несколькими компьютерами?  А если на одной флэшке удалили некий фай и пошла реакция его удаления на всех компах и флэшках, а потом кто-то этот файл восстановил в тот момент, когда этот длительный процесс не завершён? Короче, для каждого подобного случая можно найти какое-то решение, выглядящее вполне убедительным в одном случае, но приводящее к катастрофическим последствиям в другом. Ещё раз: нужен **эталон**!

Comment: @donRumata  ты написал стандартную утилиту для синхронизации, а не дал концепцию_))

Comment: @Sergey в данном случае я один буду пользоваться и флешкой и компом так что не должно возникать особо оригинальных конфликтов в логике процессов

Comment: @Gybernaty *я один буду пользоваться и флешкой и компом* - Ok! Возвращаясь к моему примеру: во время сеанса синхронизации утилита обнаруживает новый файл "А" на компе и новый файл "Б" на флшке. Возможные варианты действий утилиты: 1) Удалить оба файла. 2) "А" записать на флэшку, а "Б" - на комп 3) На обоих носителях оставить по файлу "А" 4) На обоих носителях оставить по файлу "Б". И какое решение должна принять утилита синхронизации ? :-)  И что является **последней** версией? :-) Даже если у неё будет ИИ как у трёх Эйнштейнов - она не сможет принять **всегда** правильное решение.

Comment: добавить на флешку и в локальную папку недостающие файлы и синхронизировать их содержимое самой новой версией

Comment: @Gybernaty, ок, будет тебе в следующий раз концепция.

Comment: когда в следующий раз_)

Comment: @donRumata ну где концепт?

Comment: @Gybernaty, "А пожалуйста" (с). Тут нужна консистентность для данных и идемпотентность для скорости работы.

Comment: Лучше бы промолчал)))

Comment: Что опять не так?